# iOS keychain - errSecItemNotFound with iOS 9.2 beta 3

Tags: ios, ios9, keychain

I use the keychain to store a sensitive data.

Since iOS 9.2 beta 3, I cannot retrieve a sensitive data created from a previous version of iOS (e.g. iOS 9.1).
I have an error errSecItemNotFound when using SecItemCopyMatching.
No problem with iOS 9.1 (nor iOS 9.2 beta 2 nor iOS 7.x/8.x/9.0).

Very strange: my source code creates a new sensitive data if it doesn't exist, so with iOS 9.2 beta 3 I have a new sensitive data, but if I switch back to iOS 9.1, I retrieve the old sensitive data, and so on when going back to iOS 9.2 beta 3...
As I use the exact same query, it seems the keychain is duplicated...

Here is my code to add a sensitive data:

```
NSMutableDictionary *symmetricKeyAttr = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[symmetricKeyAttr setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible];
[symmetricKeyAttr setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
[symmetricKeyAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:CSSM_ALGID_AES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];
[symmetricKeyAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:(unsigned int)(kChosenCipherKeySize << 3)] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeySizeInBits];
[symmetricKeyAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:(unsigned int)(kChosenCipherKeySize << 3)]
forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrEffectiveKeySize];
[symmetricKeyAttr setObject:(id)kCFBooleanTrue  forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrCanEncrypt];
[symmetricKeyAttr setObject:(id)kCFBooleanTrue  forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrCanDecrypt];
[symmetricKeyAttr setObject:(id)kCFBooleanFalse forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrCanDerive];
[symmetricKeyAttr setObject:(id)kCFBooleanFalse forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrCanSign];
[symmetricKeyAttr setObject:(id)kCFBooleanFalse forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrCanVerify];
[symmetricKeyAttr setObject:(id)kCFBooleanFalse forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrCanWrap];
[symmetricKeyAttr setObject:(id)kCFBooleanFalse forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrCanUnwrap];
[symmetricKeyAttr setObject:accessGroup forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessGroup];
[symmetricKeyAttr setObject:applicationTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
[symmetricKeyAttr setObject:sensitiveData forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
OSStatus sanityCheck = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) symmetricKeyAttr, NULL);
```

Here is my code to get a sensitive data:

```
NSMutableDictionary * querySymmetricKey = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[querySymmetricKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
[querySymmetricKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:CSSM_ALGID_AES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];
[querySymmetricKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnData];
[querySymmetricKey setObject:applicationTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
[querySymmetricKey setObject:accessGroup forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessGroup];
CFDataRef symmetricKeyDataRef = NULL;
OSStatus sanityCheck = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)querySymmetricKey, (CFTypeRef *)&symmetricKeyDataRef);
```

Where:

- sensitiveData is the sensitive data to store (e.g. < ac746cc2 80f72948 59d0d8b7 a5de4bad 5d9e9eb1 a400fba3 c85f3f2e 675d58bf>)
- accessGroup is the concatenation of team identifier and application
- identifier (e.g. XXXXXXXXXX.com.toto.tata) applicationTag is the tag
  related to the sensible data (e.g. <746F746F>)

Additional points:

- The issue occurs with 64-bit devices only, no problem with 32-bit devices.
- Replacing CSSM_ALGID_AES by CSSM_ALGID_NONE solves the issue (i.e. data created with iOS 9.1 can be properly retrieved with iOS 9.2 beta 3), but it's not acceptable because I must be able to read data created on iOS 9.1 with CSSM_ALGID_AES.
- The issue is not related to kSecAttrAccessGroup: I still have the problem when I remove this property.
- I've "reproduced" the issue with sample from Apple (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CryptoExercise). This sample uses CSSM_ALGID_AES too and not kSecAttrAccessGroup. Using 64-bit device: a key created with iOS 9.1 (< bdd17fe1 f515e2b1 14de7c43 c4cb6a70>) is found with iOS 9.2 beta 3 but it has a different value (<73b205e2 46230f69 fa0f347c 2958e6b1>) !! Using 32-bit device: key is the same between iOS 9.1 and iOS 9.2 beta 3.

Notes:

- I already posted this question on the Apple forum but no response from Apple... https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/87080
- I switch between iOS 9.1 and 9.2 beta 3 by using IPSW files without doing a backup restore, but I have the same problem by doing backup restore.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on iOS9.2 official, I can reproduce this on any device, tested with iPhone 6, iPhone 5S, and iPad Pro.

No problem on an iPhone 4S and iPad mini, I verified this with each device.